# python: Extracting info from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, input

teaching myself how to code and I need help

I'm trying to make sure the user inputs the right user name (credentials_U) and password (credentials_P)

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

- if they get both right it prints welcome
- if they only get the username right it prints wrong password
- if they get username wrong and or password wrong it prints incorrect and loops again.

**CURRENT OUTPUT**
returns nothing

```
directory = {"ash":"123",}

def logon():
credentials_U = input("please input your username: ")
credentials_P = input("please input you password: ")
access = False

while access != True:
    if credentials_U in directory:
        if credentials_P in directory:      #true and true
            print ("welcome")
            access = True
            break


    elif credentials_U in directory:
        if credentials_P not in directory:       #true and false
            print ("incorrect password")
            logon()


    elif credentials_U not in directory:
        if credentials_P in directory:       #false and true
            print ("incorrect")
            logon()


    elif credentials_U not in directory:
        if credentials_P not in directory:      #false and false
            print ("incorrect")
            logon()

    else:
        print("incorrect details")
        logon()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you are not accessing the `dict` properly for the fields the user enters.

Secondly you are using recursion instead of using the loop you already have.

This should be better:

```
directory = {"ash":"123",}

def logon():
    access = False
    while access != True:

        credentials_U = input("please input your username: ")
        credentials_P = input("please input you password: ")
        if credentials_U in directory:
            if credentials_P == directory[credentials_U]:      #true and true
                print ("welcome")
                access = True
            else:
                print ("incorrect password")
        else:
            print("incorrect details")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this in all places
because credentials_U will be the key and credentials_P will be the value
check below code you need to change it in entire file

```
while access != True:
    if credentials_U in directory.keys():
        if credentials_P == dictionary[credentials_U]:      #true and true
            print ("welcome")
            access = True
            break
```

Comment: With your example, if you have `dict={"ash":"123", "cait"::234"}` then the credentials 'ash' and '234' will give access when it shouldn't?

Comment: yes you are correct but i am talking about this perticular problem..

Comment: i have made some modifications in my answer this will work for all the cases

Comment: looks better now mate!